# Trying to adapt the Dojo Toolkit "Highlight Container"

Tags: dojo, containers, highlight

I am using the "Highlight Container" effect in the Dojo Toolkit (as [shown here](http://dojocampus.org/explorer/#Dojo_FX_Animate%20Property_Highlight%20Container)).

My problem comes when I have a **DIV** that contains a **TEXTAREA** instead of a text field.  I am not sure how to get it to recognize either a text field or a textarea.  The code function is as follows:

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
  dojo.query(".container input[type=text]",
  dojo.byId("topLevel"))
.onfocus(function(evt){
  //Make the background light yellow when an input gets focus
    dojo.anim(getContainer(evt.target),{backgroundColor: "#FFFFCC"});
  })
.onblur(function(evt){
  //Restore the background when an input loses focus
    dojo.anim(getContainer(evt.target), {backgroundColor: "#FFFF66"});
  })
```

});

As you can see, it's second line where the text field is found.  I guess looking for the textarea would go there as well, but I have no idea on the syntax.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Compound queries use commas:

```
dojo.query("input[type=text], textarea", ...
```

Comment: David, when an answer solves your problem, remember to accept it (use the checkmark icon below the number giving the up/down votes for the answer): that's fundamental SO etiquette!